# GWT ERROR: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SizeValidatorForString

Tags: validation, gwt, hibernate-validator

I am trying to set up client-side validation for my GWT app by following instructions provided by the following link:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation

...and by looking at the validation sample provided in:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/validation

I have set up the exact same project as in the validation sample, but as a regular GWT project - not using Maven.  I have hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar and slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar on both my client and server classpaths.  However; I am still getting the following error at runtime:

```
No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SizeValidatorForString; did you forget to inherit a required module?
No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SizeValidatorForCollection; did you forget to inherit a required module?
No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SizeValidatorForMap; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

The classes mentioned are in hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar.  Therefore, I am a bit confused.  Could it be that the super-source statement in [Validation.gwt.xml](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/validation/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/validation/Validation.gwt.xml) that is hiding the classes defined in the jar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the error: it isn't that the classes, but that the source is missing. Make sure you have a jar with the classes on the client classpath as well.

The super-source statement is used to define a package that contains source that should be used to provide client-equivalent functionality for some non-client package.

Comment: You're right Colin.  The sources were missing.  I ended up using the same hibernate version as the sample used (dunno why I didn't do so from the start).  Version 4.0.2.GA has a hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar and one for the sources: hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA-sources.jar, which was what I was missing.

Comment: Additionally, the super-source is not needed; HibernateValidator.gwt.xml does all the necessary super-sourcing.

Comment: Yep - I was just trying to explain what super-source does, as it seemed you weren't clear on how/why it is used.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have in your classpath both:hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar and hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you edit this answer to make it better , that will be really helpful.